# Display pickerInput() title when values are selected by default

Tags: r, shiny, shinywidgets

I would like to know how I could set the title of a `pickerInput()` to be displayed -`"Please select a month"`- when values are selected by default.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
  pickerInput(
    inputId = "month",
    label = "Select a month",
    choices = month.name,
    selected = month.name,
    multiple = TRUE,
    options = pickerOptions(
      actionsBox = TRUE,
      title = "Please select a month",
      header = "This is a title"
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: The picker displays the selected values if there are some. And the title is a placeholder. So what do you expect to see?

Comment: "Please select a month" when I run the app for first time while all months are selected by default. I do not know if this is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Please select a month" will display in the picker itself but only at initial execution.  Also at initial execution, all months are selected.  When any event is observed for the picker, the picker itself will then show the selected values.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
  pickerInput(
    inputId = "month",
    label = "Select a month",
    choices = month.name,
    selected = month.name,
    multiple = TRUE,
    options = pickerOptions(
      actionsBox = TRUE,
      title = "Please select a month",
      selectedTextFormat = 'static',
      header = "This is a title"
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$month, {
    updatePickerInput(session = session, inputId = "month",options = pickerOptions(selectedTextFormat = 'values'))
  }, ignoreInit = TRUE)
}  

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: no I mean the text inside the picker not the label

Comment: I just added the parameter "selectedTextFormat" in the UI.  Also, I added an "observeEvent" function in the server.  Please let me know if this answers the question.